# Slide-out vertical nav in UIExplorer example?

Tags: react-native

I'm interested in using a slide-out vertical navigation in an app using react-native. Is there a trick to this, or is it just a matter of creating a View and adding CSS that makes it respond to a button-tap or a swipe motion?

I've gone through the UIExplorer example in the Github repo, and did not see this style of navigation within it. I am new to react (and react-native, of course). I'm not having trouble with the tutorials I've gone through, just curious if there's a "React Way" to do this, or if I ought to just hack along until I get something working. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have anything specific to help you with here but I believe one difference between CSS and a potential native or JS solution is that the animations could be interruptible, giving a better user experience.

There's also this issue which seems to indicate that FB have something internal that they'll be bringing to the table soon:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/130

Comment: Actually there's a host of further reading material on github: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/search?q=animation&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Answer (score 1):

I work on the `<Navigator>` component for React Native, and I think it might fit your needs.

Check out the documentation here: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html

And the example code in UIExplorer: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/Navigator/NavigatorExample.js

The navigator is still a work in progress, so feedback is welcome! (you can file an issue on Github and tag me, @ericvicenti)